# Embed .net dll in c# .exe

Tags: c#, dll, embed

I am writing a project which makes use of the MS Chart for .net 3.5 utility.

However, either all users will also need to install this, or I need to package the dll with the program.

I can get Visual Studio to copy the dll to the folder with the program, but is it possible to make it embed the dll, so that there is only the one file?

I have seen several external programs out there, but surely there must be a way in Visual Studio - and would it work with a MS .net dll?