# Embedding .dll into .exe

Tags: c#, dll, embed, dotnetzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embed .net dll in c# .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043522/embed-net-dll-in-c-sharp-exe)

I have been trying to embed a .dll (Specifically Ionic.Zip.dll) into my application, which then compiles a new .exe using CodeDom and requires the Ionic.Zip.dll. I want to be able to distribute my program without any additional .dll's. If there is a DLL in the working directory, the program and the compiled program runs fine. I am not using ILMerge because the compiled program requires the .dll and I can't force the users to get ILMerge. However, if there isn't a .dll I get this error.

Original program won't compile the code with this error

```
error CS0006: Metadeta file 'Ionic.Zip.dll" could not be found.
```

Compiled program (Compiled while having the dll in the working directory of the original program)

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   scrub.exe
Problem Signature 02:   0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   50b0f364
Problem Signature 04:   Scrub
Problem Signature 05:   0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   50b0f364
Problem Signature 07:   1
Problem Signature 08:   38
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
```

Debug Error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Within the CodeDom compiler I have used this code:

```
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Ionic.Zip.dll");
```

To fix this I've tried this and followed it as closely as I could. http://adamthetech.com/2011/06/embed-dll-files-within-an-exe-c-sharp-winforms/

Here's my code within the original application:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
            string resource = Array.Find(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));

            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
            {
                Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        };

        InitializeComponent();

        inniZip();
     }

    private void inniZip()
    {
        Ionic.Zip.ZipOption test = new Ionic.Zip.ZipOption();
    }
```

I've put similar code in the compiled program source too.
I've been stuck on this error for a while now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance,