# Embedding external DLLs in a EXE

Tags: c#, dll, exe, embedding

I made a program for a customer with some external DLLs I copy local. The program itself is fine, but the customer wants just 1 exe-file, without the needed dlls in the folder.

I tried to use the attribute "Embed interop types" but this doesnt work. 
Another approach was something called 'monolithic' EXE-files, but I cant find anything about this in the web.

Is there a easy solution for this? Or is this not possible?

Thanks for your response.

Matthias

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed .net dll in c# .exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043522/embed-net-dll-in-c-sharp-exe)

Comment: Send him a Setup.exe.  A reasonable request, Windows users expect a functional installer that knows how to deploy the program and supports uninstallation.  A remarkably lost art these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all DLLs are .Net assemblies you could check out [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) or add the assemblies as ressource and attach to the [AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) like [mentioned here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answers so far, I'll check them out.

Ofc I can create a setup, but the customers goal is to handle the exe with a usb stick (its a test tool for their support) so he doesnt want to install anything.

Edit: Oopsie, posted my comment as answer, thanks for clearing.