# Include file in console application

Tags: batch-file, compilation

similar to this -> [Create a standalone .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124051/create-a-standalone-exe-file)

however I am not sure about the responses posted there.

I have a console application and i want to launch and execute a batch file.

build everything works fine, but when i move the compiled .exe file, it says file not found.

How do I ship test.bat with my .exe, I do not want to create an installer, rather a standalone exe. Not comfortable with ClickOnce.

[image]

**Update** Currently I add that batch file as a resource, read its contents and re-create the file in a temp location. Then execute that batch file from there. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: So the embedding works? Then the initially posted question contents is misleading and should be deleted :-)

Comment: "Update" idea is ok.

Comment: Yea, but generally was wondering, what if i have other files which are not batch, lets say EXE files or ZIP files. How can we include those in your standalone EXE ?

Comment: Use the same technique. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @wOxxOm What if my file is not a batch file? How can i still use the same technique for EXE ? [I have another such issue, but this time already compiled EXE's]

Comment: Why do you think you can't launch .exe using the same technique? Both are executable files on Windows.

Comment: With batch I am reading the contents as string and then re-creating the batch file. I don't think one can do that with compiled executables now can they?

Comment: Simply read as binary and write as binary.

Comment: oh right ! .... gee i need to go drown myself.