# Make single executable from .NET application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I've got a question regarding .NET applications and the executable that is made with the release of the application. Right now I've made my application, and it's working as intended, and I know that in the Release folder you have to final application. It works, you can run it, but my problem is in distribution.

There are a lot of extra files generated by it, and probably because of that's what it needs to get running. But is there a possibility that I can wrap everything in a package so that I can distribute one file of ~2-3mb instead of a zip file containing every file individually.

I don't want to use a setup for my applicaton, because it's very small and a standalone application is better for me. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It's for the most part DLL and XML files, see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnqeT.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed .net dll in c# .exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043522/embed-net-dll-in-c-sharp-exe)

Comment: What kind of files are you talking about? Assemblies? Images? For every type there is a solution, just explain us.

Comment: See my EDIT. It's DLL files and XML files for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ILmerge. Its a nuget package from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge. It can combine all the libraries and *.exe into one assembly. It is reliable and you can add it as part of your build events. Specifically as a Post Build Event when in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use Costura.Fody - by far the best and easiest way to embed resources in your assembly. It's available as NuGet package.

```
Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Answer (score 0):

*This what I use personally for additional application files (i.e. database scripts, images, dictionaries or whatever arbitrary data files). I did not try this approach with assemblies though.*

If you do not want to use setup, an option is to embed external files as executable application resources and extract them to application or temporary directory upon first run.

- add resource file (i.e. `Files.resx`) to your project
- in Visual Studio resource editor use option "Add Existing File"
- label the resource (i.e. `myResourceLabel`); make sure Visual Studio treats it as "FILE" resource and not i.e. "IMAGE" (it is enough to use extension ".dat" as file extension)
- from code point of view such "FILE" resource is seen as array of bytes, so you can easily extract resource data into file, i.e.:

.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("myfile.dat"))
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.dat", Files.myResourceLabel);
```